# C - values in array overriden after leaving while loop

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, while-loop

I have some strings I add into an array in a while loop. Everything is good and seems added inside the while loop, but when I leave the while loop and loop through the array to inspect the values, the last value added appears in all the indexes.

Here is the code:

```
    char buffer[50];
    char *keys[1000] = {""}; 
    int count = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
            return 1;
    } 

    while (fgets(buffer, 100, file) != NULL) {
            buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';           
            printf("Buffer being read: %s\n", buffer);
            keys[count] = buffer;
            printf("Buffer after storing: %s, index: %d\n", keys[count], count);
            count++;
            if (count == 3) {
                    break;
            }
    }

    printf("Reading from stored array\n");
    printf("%s, index: %d\n", keys[0], 0);
    printf("%s, index: %d\n", keys[1], 1);
    printf("%s, index: %d\n", keys[2], 2);
```

And here is the output:

```
Buffer being read: 0DJz9J/xOBK/chDRPFvOwg==
Buffer after storing: 0DJz9J/xOBK/chDRPFvOwg==, index: 0
Buffer being read: IHKA7WHFdhQIRpqFmqT1ew==
Buffer after storing: IHKA7WHFdhQIRpqFmqT1ew==, index: 1
Buffer being read: TtD7k1Z+4PFLfl46xWOZgQ==
Buffer after storing: TtD7k1Z+4PFLfl46xWOZgQ==, index: 2
Reading from stored array
TtD7k1Z+4PFLfl46xWOZgQ==, index: 0
TtD7k1Z+4PFLfl46xWOZgQ==, index: 1
TtD7k1Z+4PFLfl46xWOZgQ==, index: 2
```

As you can see, after I leave the while loop, somehow the values are magically over ridden.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to make a copy of the contents of the buffer, e.g. using `strdup`, or `malloc` followed by `strcpy`.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more please? Why would I need to make a copy? I am deliberately setting the array index equal to the buffer.

Comment: `char *keys[1000]` creates an array of 1000 char pointers, the first 3 you make point to `buffer` with `keys[count] = buffer;` thus printing them will always show the contents of `buffer`.

Comment: You need to copy the string from the buffer (after allocating space for the copy) and point `keys[count]` to the new copy.  Right now, you're pointing each element of `keys` at the same buffer, the contents of which change each time you read a new string into it... so you have an array with three pointers to the same memory (`buffer`), which contains whatever you read into it last.

Comment: @Dmitri AHH ok that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code:

`buffer` is defined with a size of 50 and you pass a maximum size of 100 to `fgets`:

```
fgets(buffer, 100, file);
```

You should instead increase the buffer size and use `sizeof` to keep the use and definition in sync:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file);
```

Furthermore, you should not assume that the buffer contains a final `'\n'` after a successful `fgets`.  If the file does not end with a linefeed, the final read will not store one into the buffer.  A simple and reliable way to remove the final `'\n'` if present is this:

```
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
```

You store the address of `buffer` in all your entries in the `keys` array:

```
keys[count] = buffer;
```

Be aware that this does not duplicate the contents of the array, but just stores its address.  So all entries in `keys` point to the same buffer, that has the contents of the last line read (or even undefined contents if end of file was reached).  You can fix this by allocating a copy of the string:

```
keys[count] = strdup(buffer);
```

But remember to free all these strings before returning for this function.

Comment: C gives the programmer a lot of flexibility to implement very efficient code. C generates almost no runtime checks and cannot detect many mistakes at compile time because it kept most of its original semantics and is usually configured to ignore common mistakes.  You should enable all warnings with `gcc -Wall -Werror` or similar options for `clang` or other compilers. The compiler can diagnose many problems, warnings are very useful to find them.

Comment: @Kingamere once you understand the memory model it's not so difficult . Books often do a poor job of explaining this

Comment: @immibis you already made that comment in my question above. It would've helped if you explained why they aren't stored in the array like the rest of the answers.